# Rename and download mp3 file

Tags: php, file, rename

for example i have link :

```
http://example.com/song.mp3
```

and when user download it, file will be renamed to

```
artist-song.mp3
```

I used this code :

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://example.com/song.mp3");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="a-s.mp3"');
exit();
?>
```

But it doesn't work.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

https://www.php.net/readfile

the example in the docs is pretty much what you want.

in particular, see the `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));` bit

Comment: I'm trying to do something, but i doesn't rename the file.. Maybe it's impossible to download and rename file from another server ?

Comment: yes, you can't do that. a way around it is to use your server to download the file from the origin, and then serve it to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The Location header causes the client browser to request the file from the specified URL. That'll be a completely NEW and SEPARATE http request, with its own content-type/content-disposition headers.

The Content-disposition header you're issuing here will not be honored, as it is from a completely DIFFERENT request.