# Renaming file while downloading from other website

Tags: php, .htaccess, download, rename

I am trying to rename file and download it for user!

Example...  In my website I offer to download Google Logo from my website link!
http://www.mywebsite.com/files/logo-mysite.jpg

then the file is saved as logo-mysite.jpg in the users computer but the file in real is downloaded from https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png

We can do it by saving the image from https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png temporary to our website and then auto-delete it on download or auto-delete within 1 hour!

Comment: Good .. What have you done so far ?

Comment: Actually, I tried many example. I am making a free download site... But due to inodes limit, i dont want to host file in my site! Rather user can download from external source.... but the files are renamed with our website name in the trace!

Comment: But I can store files for few hours in my server, if user request to download the file!

Comment: You would still be using a lot of bandwidth ... ???

Comment: Why not use a free `CDN` to store the images then redirect the users ?

Comment: Actually.... I have wallpaper section which resize the file to various different screen resolution from mobile to desktop... so I need to do something tough job!.... I never heard of free CDN!

Comment: You can use http://imgur.com/ to do all that ... and its fee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suggest a filename for a download by adding a content-disposition header:

```
header('Content-disposition', 'attachment;filename=logo-mysite.jpg');
die(file_get_contents('https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png'));
```

Obviously this would give problems since you are downloading a png file with a jpg extension, but I'm just following your question... To convert the image you'd need to add some lines of GD2 code.

Comment: Do it work if we have the original file of other website??? I dont think so!
Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144270/rename-and-download-mp3-file?rq=1

Comment: No, you can only control the filename if you 'pass it through'. I'll edit my example, that part of the question was unclear.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure this is the only real solution to your question  :)

Comment: There's not much to explain, put it in a PHP file and it works...?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `header()` function to set the name that the user will download:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=logo-mysite.png');

// Open the new file, and dump it out to the user
$handle = fopen( "https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png" );
fpassthru( $handle );
fclose( $handle );
```

If you really want to convert it from jpg to png, you'll need to run it through ImageMagick or the likes.